# SQL Select * from table1 and few column in table 2 statements and with condition

Tags: sql-server

```
 familyInfo Table
pFnumber
pInterviewee
pInterviewed


personInfo Table
pControlNo
pLname
pFname
```

How do I create an sql statement that returns all information about `familyInfo` table and `pLname` and `pFname` from `personInfo` table with the condition pFnumber = 1 and pControlNo = 1

Will appreciate the help

Comment: The question is unclear. Clarify by providing sample data and expected results.

Comment: @wewesthemenace here ya go. I hope it clarify things

Comment: Thanks but could you add sample data and your expected result?

Comment: Also: is this mysql, or sql server? Those are two very different database engines, and what works for one doesn't always work for the other. Please **edit your question** to remove the wrong tag.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn its an sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM FAMILYINFO AS F
INNER JOIN PERSONINFO AS P ON F.PFNUMBER = P.PCONTROLNO
WHERE F.PFNUMBER = 1
```

Edited to include a left outer join after reading your comment. I believe you said that data might not always be in familyinfo, but you would always have a plname record.

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONINFO AS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN FAMILYINFO AS F ON P.PCONTROLNO = F.PFNUMBER 
AND F.PFNUMBER = 1
```

Comment: Hey there is multiple results which is right but is it possible that the interviewee will merge? but the pLname and pFname will still display?

Comment: I tried the second sql query its almost right but the problem is it also shows all the information in table `personInfo` like there is no condition.

Comment: Remove the * and only select the fields you want to see.
select p.plname, p.pfname, f.pinterviewee, etc.

Comment: It shows all the information in table `PersonInfo` the query ignores the condition. It display the information about `pfnumber` 1 to 5